plot grid error 'Cannot convert object of class numeric into a grob.' but all of my object are class "gg"

I'm trying to generate a plot combining 9 plots using the function plot_grid.
Here is my script :
plot_grid(plot_grid(penchy, pver, pplante, ncol=3),   plot_grid(p_adplante_benchy, p_adver_benchy, ncol=2),   plot_grid(p_adplante_bver, p_adenchy_bver, ncol=2),   plot_grid(p_adenchy_bplante, p_adver_bplante, col=2),   ncol = 1 )

The displayed graphs looks like the image attached and the following error message occurs : Cannot convert object of class numeric into a grob.
The first row with 3 graphes is okay, the second row with two graphs is okay, the third row with 2 graphs is okay, but the last row looks "flattened"
More infos about the graphs you could need : y axis is always numeric, x axis is always a factor, and a discrete value (factor) is used to display the points with two different shapes and colors. I am using the last version of Rstudio (2024.04.2+764)
Do you have any idea what the problem is and how can I solve it ?
Thank you in advance ;)
I checked one by one all of my graphs and they all are gg class. I tried to convert them as grob, using grid.arrange and arrangeGrob but the result is exactly the same.
I tried to change the y scale of my last graph as it is really bigger than the other ones but nothing changes either.
When I print the graphs one by one, no problem seems to occur.
There is a blank thin line under the last line, I think the problem might be there but I have no idea how to deal with it...

I would highly suggest that you use the patchwork package instead. https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/ BTW, RStudio is just an IDE, it doesn't have any bearing on your problem.

As suggested by @Phil, try patchwork or cowplot to combine ggplot objects. If that doesn't solve your issue, update your question with a minimal reproducible example.
